# C# generic delegate type inference

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Why can't the C# compiler infer T to int in the specified example?

```
void Main()
{
    int a = 0;
    Parse("1", x => a = x);
    // Compiler error:
    // Cannot convert expression type 'int' to return type 'T'
}

public void Parse<T>(string x, Func<T, T> setter)
{
    var parsed = ....
    setter(parsed);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't infer also. Try `Parse<int>(...)`

Comment: Syntactic sugar for a parsing method. I could do it with expressions, but then I would have to use refelection, which is a no go.

Comment: `Expression` is not `reflection`. Please show the full code of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @L.B that is exactly what I'm doing now. But I was wondering why the compiler isn't able to figure it out, since 'x => a = x' returns an int.

Comment: @gdoron I could use expressions to get the PropertyInfo of the property I'm trying to set, but I would have to use reflection to invoke it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method type inference on a lambda requires that the types of the *lambda parameters* be already known before the types of the *returns* are inferred. So for example if you had:

```
void M<A, B, C>(A a, Func<A, B> f1, Func<B, C> f2) { }
```

and a call

```
M(1, a=>a.ToString(), b=>b.Length);
```

then we would infer:

```
A is int, from the first argument
Therefore the second parameter is Func<int, B>. 
Therefore the second argument is (int a)=>a.ToString();
Therefore B is string.
Therefore the third parameter is Func<string, C>
Therefore the third argument is (string b)=>b.Length
Therefore C is int.
And we're done.
```

See, we need A to work out B, and B to work out C. In your case you want to work out T from... T.  And you can't do that.

Comment: it really seems obvious when you put it like that... :)

Comment: Why partial generics inference wasn't added to the language?

Comment: @ceztko: Language designers are not required to list reasons why features were not added to the language! There are infinitely many possible features and we haven't come up with reasons for all of them to not do them. Rather, features must be justified by the people who want them. If you have a proposal for a language feature, do feel free to design it and propose it on github.

Comment: Fair enough. Sometimes development is also driven by "completionism", though.

Comment: @ceztko: That's correct: *completeness* and *consistency* are both design criteria but I think of them as "weak" criteria. That is, given the choice between a "complete" design and a "missing some cases" design that are in other respects similar, we'd try to choose the "complete" design. The problem is that the designs are *never* "in all other respects similar". An example might help. We added extension methods in C# 3.0. Why not go for completeness and also add extension properties/constructors/indexers/operators... ?

Comment: Because of budgets, that's why. We had a design for extension properties, realized that it added a huge amount of schedule pressure without making LINQ work any better, and promptly cut it. *Completeness is expensive*, both because it has direct costs -- someone has to design, implement, test, document and ship the feature -- and because it has *opportunity costs* -- the time you spend doing an unnecessary completionist feature is time you're not adding a feature someone actually *needs*.

Comment: On the topic of extension method completeness, [Proposal: Static extension methods](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/2505) makes for good reading.  It shows how a "simple" feature can be especially complicated.  It also has numerous reasonable-looking proposals, with experts explaining the problems found in those proposals.

Answer (score 2):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx section on generic methods.

> Note that the compiler cannot infer the type based on the type of the
>   returned value alone.