# C# method group type inference

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I'm trying to write a generic method that supplies parameters and calls a function, like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public int Method(float arg) => 0;
}

TResult Call<T1, TResult>(Func<T1, TResult> func) =>
    func(default(T1));

void Main()
{
    var m = new MyClass();
    var r1 = Call<float, int>(m.Method);
    var r2 = Call(m.Method); // CS0411
}
```

The last line fails to compile with [CS0411](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxfhx4sy(v=vs.140).aspx). Is there any workaround to get type inference to work here?

Use case: using AutoFixture to generate function call parameters.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Related(?): http://stackoverflow.com/a/9331879/3225495

Comment: It's not related, in his case the two types are independent and both given by the method handle. C# could, theoretically, fully infer the correct generic arguments. The standard just doesn't require it for complexity reasons.

Comment: If you're only going to call the default of the type on the method via Call, then you could just overload the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately no, that's a limitation of type inference in C#. It doesn't really do much with return types, which is what's needed in your case to fully infer the generic arguments to `Call<>`.