# Why do I have to explicitly specify my type arguments for Func parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, functional-programming, delegates

I am writing a simple `Memoize` helper that allows caching method results instead of computing them every time. However, when I try to pass a method into `Memoize`, the compiler can't determine the type arguments. Aren't they obvious from my method signature? Is there a way around this?

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

public static class Program
{
    public static Func<T, V> Memoize<T, V>(Func<T, V> f)
    {
        var cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, V>();
        return a => cache.GetOrAdd(a, f);
    }

    // This is the method I wish to memoize
    public static int DoIt(string a) => a.Length;        

    static void Main()
    {
        // This line fails to compile (see later for error message)
        var cached1 = Memoize(DoIt);

        // This works, but is ugly (and doesn't scale to lots of type parameters)
        var cached2 = Memoize<string, int>(DoIt);
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'Program.Memoize<T, V>(Func<T, V>)'
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Comment: Any reason you haven't included your complete example directly in the question? That would make the question better, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet added the complete example directly. Quite lengthy imo )

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the `Control.Invoke` version either, as that's trying to convert a method group to just `Delegate` rather than a specific delegate type. This question is about generic type inference with method group conversions.

Comment: @AlexeiS: You could probably remove the `System.Diagnostics` import, and the extension method, and all the code that uses `Console`, if you wanted to make it shorter. (It's not about believing that the code works after it compiles, it's about the compiler handling.) It's already much, much shorter than many questions though - good job, in general.

Comment: (I'd also say that with the complete example in the question, you don't need the link and you probably don't need the snippets of it before the actual code. If you'd like me to edit it into what I'd consider the ideal way of asking the question, let me know.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't see how it differs to be honest. Anyway, there are ton of other duplicates then, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36019983/5311735

Comment: @Evk: That's a better duplicate - but there's a *huge* difference between a call to `Foo(Delegate d)` and `Foo<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2> f)`. The answers to those questions are entirely different.

Comment: (I think this is a better question than that one, personally - I'd rather that one were closed as a duplicate of this than vice versa.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes please, feel free to remove parts of the code that makes it not ideal )

Comment: @AlexeiS: Done - see if you're happy with the change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Isn't `DoIt()` signature compatible with `Func<string, int>`?

Yes it is. It's fine to convert it to that specific type, like this for example:

```
Func<string, int> func = DoIt;
var cachedDoit = Memoize(func);
```

The problem you're running into is that type inference basically doesn't work particularly well with *method group conversions*. When you pass `DoIt` as an argument, that's a method group. In your case it only refers to a single method, but it could refer to multiple methods, with different signatures... and that complicates things.

I often see this come up with LINQ, where I'd like to call `foo.Select(SomeMethodGroup)`, but type inference fails. There's *some* support for method groups within type inference, but it's not everything we might want it to be.

This isn't a matter of the C# team being lazy... type inference is *hugely* complicated, and any change is really fraught with danger in terms of backward compatibility. It's in section 7.5.2 of the C# 5 specification if you want to have a look - but frankly that's part of the spec where I get lost really quickly.